# Fail to update value using window.setInterval, useEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, setinterval

Here, I am simulating a timer with some model result that depends on the timer value. I want to update the timer while changing the model value every second.

```js
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function calculateDuration(startTimestamp) {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  const timestamp = currentDate.getTime();
  const duration = timestamp - startTimestamp;
  return Math.round(duration / 1000);
}

function calculateModelResult(duration) {
  return duration * 0.1;
}

export default function Page() {
  const startTime = 1692699200000;
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [modelResult, setModelResult] = useState(0);
  const testTimeRef = useRef(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    testTimeRef.current = window.setInterval(() => {
      setDuration(calculateDuration(startTime));
      setModelResult(calculateModelResult(duration));
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <h1>
      Hello, the duration is {duration}, the model result based on the current
      time is {modelResult}
    </h1>
  );
}
```

However, the `modelResult` keep staying 0 without changing, the `duration` works well.

Look like this:

```
Hello, the duration is 80188, the model result based on the current time is 0
```

```
Hello, the duration is 80196, the model result based on the current time is 0
```

How should I correct the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect` is only run once and it has access to only the original values of `duration` and `startTime`. So all calls to `calculateDuration` are passed the same `duration` parameter and the calculation never changes.

Use

```js
useEffect(() => {
  testTimeRef.current = window.setInterval(() => {
    const newDuration = calculateDuration(startTime);
    setDuration(newDuration);
    setModelResult(calculateModelResult(newDuration));

  }, 1000);

  // also return a function to clear the interval when the component is unmounted
  return () => {
    window.clearInterval(testTimeRef.current);
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I am still think why I call `setDuration` before `setModelResult`, the `duration` should update before I call `setModelResult`, then why `setModelResult` is still using the original value of `duration` instead of the update after `setDuration`.

Comment: First of all, the `setDuration` does not instantly update the duration. The new duration will be available in the next render of the component. You should read more about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and the "stale closure" problem.

Comment: thank you, may I ask why should I add `return () =>{window.clearInterval(testTimeRef.current)}`?

Comment: Because if you unmount the `Page` component the interval will continue running and trying to set the state of something that has been removed. If your `Page` component is the "top" container then you might not really need to, but it is a good practice to always clean up any subscriptions or timers when a component is unmounted.